# first occurrence of the angry police boss chewing out his/her subordinates

Tags: first-appearance

It's really the highlight of the genre: the sergeant, lieutenant, or chief has the commissioner or mayor "breathing down my neck," and they sometimes have got "my nuts in a vice" because the protagonist is a loose cannon who refuses to play by the rules. This is the protagonist's final warning: if they can't clean up their act, they'll have to turn in their gun and badge.

I'm looking for the first movie to feature a recognizable version of this staple.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DaChief

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *Dirty Harry* (1971), maybe

It is very difficult to answer this question without watching *every* Hollywood movie about police officers. My approach to finding the first police lieutenant who chewed out a loose cannon who played by his own rules would be to find the first loose cannon who played by his own rules. The first one I can think of is Harry Callahan, first appearing in 1971 in *Dirty Harry*. In that film, Callahan had several superiors who chewed him out:

> You're lucky I'm not indicting you for assault with intent to commit murder! Where the hell does it say you've got a right to kick down doors, torture suspects, deny medical attention and legal counsel? Where have you been? Does Escobido ring a bell? Miranda? You *must* have heard of the Fourth Amendment! What I'm saying is, that man had rights!

If you can find an earlier movie cop who was a loose cannon playing by his own rules, my bet is you'll find an earlier irate sergeant/lieutenant/chief/DA who's got the mayor breathing down his neck.

(Also worth mentioning that the trope may have originated on television, though you only ask for the first movie).

Comment: Dammit, ruffdove, you get results.

Comment: I especially appreciate the methodological insight. Makes me wonder if there's an irate police lieutenant somewhere who's threatening to confiscate _ruffdove_'s badge and gun...

Comment: Yeah, he's always on my a**. I'm too old for this s***.